# How can a printer installation change the default printer of other computers?

Tags: windows, printer

I have a Canon MG3550 installed on my network. I went through the Canon setup on the computer I wanted to use it on and it took the SSID and password and saved them in the printer.

It then proceeded to change the default printer of many of the other computers on the network, despite not being explicitly asked to.

I have two questions:

a) How can a printer do this? Aren't there security features to prevent this kind of behaviour?

b) How can I prevent this happening in future?

Comment: Did you install this printer to the other computers on the network? What OS are the computers? What type of network are you using?

Comment: They're all running windows 7/8 and no, I didn't install them on the other computers. We have a Wireless AP connected to a Cisco managed router.

Comment: Did you use the same IP address for this printer, or do you use DHCP for the printer and did it get the IP address of the old printer?

Comment: This wasn't a replacement printer. It chose it's own IP address and I wasn't given the option to choose one. It's presumable using DHCP.

Comment: Is there some policy active that distributes printer settings across the network? Are you using AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printer isn't doing this, Windows is. When Windows sees the network printer it automatically installs the drivers for it. To turn this feature off you can follow these steps. *(NOTE: these steps are for Windows 7. I don't have a Windows 8 machine handy to check it, but the steps should be similar)*

1. Open Printers and Devices
2. Locate the Computer under `Devices` (this will be labeled as the
   computer name)
3. Right click the computer and select `Device installation settings`
   [image]
4. On the `Device installation settings` window choose `Never install
   drivers from Windows Update`
   [image]
5. Click <kbd>Save changes</kbd>

[source](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/stop-windows-7-from-automatically-installing-device-drivers/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does this mean that the print drivers are changing the default printer or Windows is making assumptions? This is not the only network printer and the others do not do this.

Comment: Not sure. I believe it has to do with the drivers which are installed automatically. Some common printer drivers may be native to Windows, therefore not downloading from Windows Update and installing autonomously.

Comment: It turns out Windows does this often - but this printer is particularly bad for it. We have since stopped using it. Many thanks.